# Discovering RN4020 BLE Services from a Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I guess I misunderstood the concept of Private services.
I've a program using Apple CoreBluetooth , and it seems that everything is fine discovering services:

```
Found Characteristic 'Appearence' for service 'Generic Access Profile' 
Found Characteristic 'Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters' for service 'Generic Access Profile' 
Found Characteristic 'Serial Number String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Hardware Revision String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Firmware Revision String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Software Revision String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Manufacturer Name String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Model Number String' for service 'Device Information' 
Found Characteristic 'Battery Level' for service 'Battery'
```

Then I Set Up Private Service and Characteristics in the RN4020, so when I type LS in the terminal I can see them:

```
123456789012345678901234567890FF
  12345678901234567890123456789011,000B,02,01
  12345678901234567890123456789011,000C,10,02
  12345678901234567890123456789022,000E,02,02
```

Then I start advertisement, restart...but I can't see this service from my Application (?). It's because they are private ? so how can I make it then public ?
and shouldn't I see as well all these services (Battery, Device Information & Generic Access Profile) in the terminal when I type LS ????

Thanks !

Comment: Did you solved that? its really unbelievable how Microchip is letting this happen, we are struggling days  can't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about MAC specifically but I ran into a similar issue in Android where the remote device had to be cleared from androids memory before it would show the new services/characteristics